# Are there any sensors that are capable of measuring audio pitch for EV3?

Tags: ev3, sensor

Are there any sensors that are capable of measuring audio pitch? Or is there an easy solution that a beginner would be able to make work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to rig something up with a [Vernier Sensor Adapter](http://www.vernier.com/products/interfaces/bta-nxt/), the [Vernier EV3 Sensor Block](https://www.vernier.com/engineering/lego-ev3/ev3-sensor-block/), and a [Vernier microphone](https://www.vernier.com/products/sensors/mca-bta/). Although the [NXT sound sensor can be made compatible with EV3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55A5OT71bAc), it would seem it only measures volume, and cannot measure frequency.

Comment: It looks like the Vernier microphone is no different that the NXT sound sensor. The EV3 is only capable of sampling at 1kHz, so either of these could only be used to detect frequencies < 500Hz and you would have to write your own DSP for this to extract the frequency from the samples.

Comment: i might try ev3dev python with a usb microphone and see how that goes